# How to show different button in template according to user logged in in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I need to show different button in my template based on user's log in. The scenario is my template show follow button:

```
Check whether the user logged in or not-
  if user logged in-
   check which channel he follwed:
     if he followed any channel 
       beside that channel name show "followed" button
     else
       show "follow" button with the path follow_save 
  elif user not logged in:
     show follow button with the path follow_save
```

I am stuck how to do that? Is this a task for views or for template? how to do that? Any help from you experts will save me..Also I have wanted to take the user_id from session.
Here is my views.py

```
e= EventArchiveGallery.objects.all()   
user = request.session['user_id']
if user:
    j = EventArchiveGallery()
    joining_list = j.joiningList(user)         

return render_to_response('gallery/allevents.html',
{
    'joining_list':joining_list,
},
context_instance=RequestContext(request)                         
)
```

This is my templates:

```
{% for event in live %}
    <p>Event Title:{{event.event_title}}<p/>
    <p>Channel Name:{{event.channel_id.channel_title}}</p>
    <p>Event Description{{event.event_description}}</p>
    {% if event in joining_list %}
        <p>followed</p>
            {%else%}
                    <p>follow</p> #I have wanted to show follow_save function call from this button,when user clicked
            {endif%}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on? Show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I have added some code in my question..But I think my views.py is not correct.Cause it showed key error user_id..

Comment: @HasanFaisal Do you have the `auth` module within your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: You should read the [authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests) which explain this.

Comment: In my setting I have both auth modules and session

Comment: I have implemented the login function and form using the django authentication..

Answer (score 0):

You are asking 2 questions better if you can split in 2 questions, anyway ...

- show different button in my template based on user's log in

  - Better way would be identify what to show in view and pass context parameter to template. Depending upon this variable template will render different HTML.

example template : Assumes view passes `followed_channel` parameter.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {%if followed_channel %}
        {# render html you want #}
    {%else%}
        {# render another way #}
    {%endif%}
{%endif%}
```

- Also I have wanted to take the user_id from session

Before you get from session, you have to store it. So you can update your view as

```
e= EventArchiveGallery.objects.all()   
user = request.session.get('user_id')
if not user:
     request.session['user_id'] = request.user.id
if user:
    j = EventArchiveGallery()
    joining_list = j.joiningList(user)         

return render_to_response('gallery/allevents.html',
{
    'joining_list':joining_list,
},
context_instance=RequestContext(request)                         
)
```